# How can we set a cell value to align center in Spotfire Graphical table?

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to align graphical table numerical cell values to align center.Please let me know if there is a way to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of Spotfire 7.0.1, you can not, unfortunately. I don't think this has changed in newer versions.