# In spotfire how we can allign cell values

Tags: spotfire

Anyone know of a way to align cell values in a table or cross table visualization in Spotfire? Like you can do in Excel ... Left, Right, or Center

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.9.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-A721BAAB-AC52-464B-BCAA-3222B0072BEF.html) explains how to do it in 7.9. It should be the same down to version 7.6. Since you didn't specify your version, it's hard to tell. [Niko states that you can't as of 7.0.1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851411/how-can-we-set-a-cell-value-to-align-center-in-spotfire-graphical-table) Also, this won't be the same for all table types (details on demand, cross table, summary table, etc)

Comment: as @scsimon mentions, this is a feature that is only available from version 7.6 forward.